# Including Boost network libraries makes Windows.h functions undefined

Tags: c++, visual-studio, winapi, boost, boost-asio

I'm trying to work with boost

My includes look like this:

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <Windows.h>
```

I'm trying to test out this call:

```
ShellExecute(NULL, "open", "C:/local/test.txt", NULL, NULL, SW_SHOWNORMAL);
```

When I compile I get "ShellExecute is undefined". If I move the `Windows.h` include above the boost include, it's picked up by the compiler but I get tons of Winsock errors instead. I'm using VS 2015.

This only happens with the network libraries - I've been using boost filesystem prior to this with no problems.

This happens with all functions that are provided by `Windows.h`

Any thoughts would be appreciated!

Comment: You are doing battle with Boost using WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN in its private .h files.  Very naughty.  Best way is to `#include <Winsock2.h>` yourself first so Boost doesn't try it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to `#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN` prior to including *Windows.h*, to prevent it from dragging in the Windows Sockets 1 headers (see [Using the Windows Headers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383745.aspx)). Those headers collide with the Windows Sockets 2 headers used by boost asio.

The following fixes the issues with colliding Windows Sockets declarations:

```
#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN
#include <Windows.h>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
```

Note: Keep in mind, that defining the `WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN` preprocessor symbol skips inclusion of a number of system headers. To account for that, you need to explicitly include them. In case of [ShellExecute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762153.aspx) this would be `#include <Shellapi.h>`.

Comment: Hmm thanks for pointing me in the right direction but this doesn't fix it - just using `WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN` with no headers besides Windows.h causes `ShellExecute` to be undefined. Same problem as the OP when the Boost libraries are included.

Comment: @matt: You need to `#include <Shellapi.h>` to use [ShellExecute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762153.aspx). The documentation tells you, which header to include (and which libraries to link against).

Comment: Thanks for your help, I managed to get it working, I was fumbling around a lot. :)